# How to find the index of a set in Julia/JuMP?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am trying to create a linear optimization model. I have a set that looks like this:

```
si=[1,51,39,400909,1244]
sj=[31,47,5]
```

The numbers in this set represent codes. I am trying to loop through the set to add a constraint to my model, but I do not want to loop through the sets using their values, I want to loop through the sets based on their indices. 
Here is the code I have now:

```
si=[1,51,39,400909,1244]
sj=[31,47,5]

c= [3 5 2;
    4 3 5;
    4 5 3;
    5 4 3;
    3 5 4]
b= [80;
    75;
    80;
    120;
    60]
# x_ij >= 0  ∀ i = 1,...,5, j = 1,...,3
@defVar(m, x[i in si,j in sj] >= 0)
@setObjective(m,Min,sum{c[i,j]*x[i,j],i in si, j in sj})
# ∀j = 1,...,3
for j in sj
    @addConstraint(m, sum{x[i,j],i in si} <= 480)
end
for i in si
    @addConstraint(m, sum{x[i,j],j in sj} >= b[i])
end
```

I keep getting an error because the numbers in the sets are too big. Does anyone know how to loop through the indices instead? Or does anyone have another way to do this?

I am also having trouble printing my solution. Here is my code:

```
for i in n
    for j in p
        println("x",i,",",j,"= ", getValue(x[i,j]))
    end
end (incorporating Iain Dunning's answer from below)
```

However the output only reads

```
 Objective value: 1165.0
x5,3= 0.0
```

Do you know how to fix the output so I can read the values of my variables?

Comment: Please remember to accept answers to your previous questions - this will encourage people to answer your new questions!

Comment: When you say "set" it looks like you mean list/array and this is a material consideration. You can't index into a set. I'm not sure you can loop through a set either you might need to use collect(). Loop thorough indices? You mean something along the lines of list=[list[x] for x in [1:length(list)]]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have posted doesn't work because you are trying to index `c` by, e.g. `400909,47`. Try this:

```
n = length(si)
p = length(sj)

@variable(m, x[i=1:n,j=1:p] >= 0)
@objective(m,Min,sum{c[i,j]*x[i,j],i=1:n,j=1:p})
for j in 1:p
    @constraint(m, sum{x[i,j],i=1:n} <= 480)
end
for i in 1:n
    @constraint(m, sum{x[i,j],j=1:p} >= b[i])
end
```

Comment: that worked! however I am having problem trying to do that when printing my variables out. I added to my question with the code for the new error I am having. Hopefully you have an answer!

Comment: You need `1:n`, e.g. `for i in 1:n` - right now you just have `for i in n`